# Computer won't boot after installing 32GB RAM kit

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

Computer configuration:

- **CPU**: Intel Core i5-7600K, 7th gen
- **MB**: ASUS H110I-PLUS, allows up to 2 DIMM slots, max. 32GB and 2400MHz
- **RAM**: Corsair Vengeance LPX, 32GB (2x16GB), 2400MHz, CL16, 1.2v (CMK32GX4M2A2400C16)

Research done:

- Meets MB requirements: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H110I-PLUS/specifications
- Is not officially tested by ASUS, but that does not mean it is not supported: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H110I-PLUS/HelpDesk_QVL/
- Tried also when "memory isn't detected": https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1039574
- Installed BIOS version is 4212 (latest currently): https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H110I-PLUS/HelpDesk_BIOS/
- Both DIMM slots and the RAM modules are functional.

The problem:

- One DIMM boots flawless.
- Two DIMMs starts up the computer with no beep, no display, no boot, no HDD sound activity. Why?

Comment: "Is not officially tested by ASUS, but that does not mean it is not supported:" Does not mean it is either, evidently it is not compatible.

Comment: @Moab you mean not compatible as Dual Channel? the BIOS accepts a DIMM in Single Channel and this it is not listed either in the QVL.

Comment: There is no way we can diagnose this type of problem, I would try different or proven compatible memory kit.

Comment: When with one RAM stick it boots, have you tested that single RAM stick in both the slots one by one and also repeated the same for the other RAM stick as well?